# How to change toolbar icon on fragment change from bottom navigation, using Navigation Component Lib?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-bottomnav

I've setup my bottom navigation with navHostController, I've a container activity which has a toolbar, I want to change the icon in toolbar based on which fragment I'm on, this was easy if I didn't use navigation Component library.

MainActivity

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(dashboardNavHostFragment.findNavController())
}
```

[image]

I want to change the icon in the toolbar to the fragment active in the bottom navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `addOnDestinationChangedListener`.
Something like:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
   if(destination.id == R.id.xxxx) {
       toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.xxxx)
   } else {
       //
   }
}
```